# In constexpr function breakpoint is hit

Tags: c++, encryption, visual-studio-2017, c++17, constexpr

Here is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


template <int ...I>
class MetaString
{
    char buffer_[sizeof...(I)+1];
public:
    // A constexpr constructor 
    constexpr MetaString(const char * arg) :buffer_{ encrypt(arg[I])... }
    {}
    constexpr const char *get()const { return buffer_; }
private:

    constexpr char encrypt(const char c) const { return c ^ 0x55; }
};

char *decrypt(const char* buffer_, int size)
{
    char* tmp = (char *)malloc(size + 1);

    strcpy_s(tmp, size + 10, buffer_);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(tmp + i) = *(tmp + i) ^ 0x55;
    }

    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr MetaString<0,1,2,3,5> var("Post Malone");

    char * var1 = decrypt(var.get(), 5);
    std::cout <<  var1 << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

The idea is simple, I create object of `MetaString` and provide some `string` to it. The constructor encrypts the argument by `XOR`. Then I have `decrypt` function which decrypts value back.

The problem is that I set breakpoint in constructor (specifically this line `constexpr MetaString(const char * arg) :buffer_{ encrypt(arg[I])... }`) and it is hit when I run in debugging mode. Which as I understand means that the constructor is called during runtime.

To guarantee that functions be evaluated at compile time I created object this way `constexpr MetaString<0,1,2,3,5> var("Post Malone");` But I've read that `constexpr` variable must be literal type.

So my question is how can I manage to have variable like `var` (which would have encrypted data in it and be evaluated at compilation time) and then call `decrypt` at runtime and get original value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` only guarantees that a function or variable *can* be used in a constant expression. It does not guarantee that a function/object is going to always be evaluated/constructed at compiletime. In your particular case, that's actually not really possible since we're talking about an object with automatic storage duration. The object, if it is going to be created, can only really be created when the program is running. Try making your variable `static`…

Comment: `constexpr` is a bit overrated and often misunderstood.

Comment: you mean create variable like this `static constexpr MetaString<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>var("PostMalone");`?

Comment: @user3503143 yes. I have to say though that I can't really reproduce the issue here either way…

Comment: That helped! But I have one more question: As I know static variables(objects) are created when the program flow encounters the declaration and it is destroyed when program is terminated. You said that `The object, if it is going to be created, can only really be created when the program is running.`  how come that making it static made it evaluate during compilation?